# Ruby array to file time stamps shouldn't be there

Tags: arrays, ruby

I am creating a parsing file that reads through some HTML files. The program opens up the files then sends certain lines to a method that replaces some of the information then sends it to an array.

But when I send the array to a file to be saved I am getting some weird output. Here is on of the lines of the text file.

`\e[0;32;49mDaily 9:35\e[0m`

In the method I am not putting in the `\e[0;32;49m` or the `\e[0m`.

Why are these characters being added to my output?

Comment: Those are colors. DO you use some sort of library to colorize the output in your terminal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are [ANSI](http://misc.flogisoft.com/bash/tip_colors_and_formatting) colors and are used by the terminal to display a prettier output.

Example, if I create a file with `puts "\e[0;32;49mDaily 9:35\e[0m"` and use a terminal that can interpret that language I will see a colored output.

[image]

Now I can only assume that you terminal can't read that color and that's why you see that weird code inside your string.

Comment: Yep I actually just figured that out is was kinda weird put yeah I removed the color codes just to see if that would change anything and it fixed it. Thank you for the quick response tho! Also that helped me to confirm my thought of what is could of been.

Comment: Hehe, I'm glad you fixed it.